# Generic element_at array using void** macro

Tags: c, macros

I have the following example of a C macro:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_AT(array , i, elem_size) \
*((void **)((((void *)array) + i * elem_size)))

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long array[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};

    long a = ARRAY_AT(array , 2, sizeof(long)); // a = 3

    return 0;
   }
```

I don't really understand the *(void**) part, how does it work?

Comment: Ouch.  That's **horrible** code. For one, it's doing pointer arithmetic on a `void *`, and it's a strict aliasing violation waiting to happen.

Comment: The line `long a = ARRAY_AT(array , 2, sizeof(long));` generates the compiler error *C2036: 'void *': unknown size*. Have you written some code yourself that you need guidance for?

Comment: If you have an array and need to get the Nth element out of it, just dereference the array: `array[N]`.  That macro is worse than useless - it not only doesn't solve any problem because to use it you need to have the array, the desired element, and the type of the array - all that's needed to dereference the array and get the element in the first place.  It's also wrong and confusing.  I'm not going to bother taking it apart element by element because you need to toss it into the bit bucket and never use it.

Comment: You are all totally right, it is only for educational purpose, to understand how the pointers, and void pointers work.

Comment: I guess the educational takeaway is "how not to use pointers".  That said, learning how not to do something is an underrated educational experience.